# PixabayがWordPressで使えません

Tags: wordpress, ssl

> certificate subject name (*.opendns.com) does not match target host name 'github.com' while accessing https://github.com/

というメッセージが出て使えません。
どのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

Comment: PixabayとWordPressの関係や、何をどの様な手順で行ったら、どのようにエラーとなったか等、詳しく教えて下さい。WordPressのプラグインか何かの質問ですか？タグにsslがついていますが、どの様な関係が？

Answer (score 1):

Pixabayは「WordPress」のプラグインで、エディタの編集画面でPixabayの版権フリー写真を一発挿入出来るという物です。

> 質問主さん
>   興味深い事例ですが、「設定」に入り、「設定」画面の変更で使える様になりませんか?

Comment: それでもなんとも成らない場合は、ネット接続そのものか、またはパソコン上に、ページの安全な読み込みを阻むなんらかの要因がある様に思います。異なったパソコンまたは異なった接続環境でも、アラートが出るかをチェックしてみてください。